# Calculating acceleration peak from velocity

Tags: matlab, acceleration

I am trying to convert an array of velocity values to acceleration values. I understand that acceleration is the integral of velocity, but don't know how to acheive this. I am using MATLAB, so if anyone can offer a solution in this language, I would be very grateful! See the graph below:

[image]

The yellow line plots the velocity and the vertical dotted lines show the peaks and troughs of that waveform (peaks and troughs found using [peakdet](http://www.billauer.co.il/peakdet.html)). The green horizontal stuff in the middle is unrelated to this question.

What I am trying to isolate is the steepest part of the large downward slopes on the curve above. Can anyone offer any advice on how to calculate this?

P.S. I am aware that quad() is the function used to integrate in MATLAB but don't know how to implement it in this situation.

Comment: I think you mean that acceleration is the derivative of velocity, not integral. Also, is this a one-dimensional problem, or is this just recording the speed of a higher-dimensional motion? If it's the latter, then things can be slightly more complicated. ... I think you can just use a difference stencil and compute the numerical derivative of your velocity curve to get acceleration. Check Matlab's `diff()` and `gradient()` function (but you might want to use a better stencil and just code it yourself).

Comment: Thanks very much. It IS one-dimensional. Your 'gradient' suggestion looks like it might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceleration is a *derivative* of velocity.

If your velocity values are stored in `v`, you can get a quick numerical derivative of `v` with

```
a = diff(v)
```

Be aware that if `v` is a real rather than synthetic signal, `a` is likely to be pretty noisy, so some smoothing may be in order, depending on how you're going to use it.

Comment: Since he wants to find the steepest part of right side you might add `[val,idx] = max(a);` or similar.